# Rearrange array elements from the updated indexing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet

I don't really know how to explain my problem so sorry for the title.

I have three JavaScript arrays:

```
//indexing array
originalData = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']

//target array
originalPos = ['50 a', '80 b', '31 c']

//updated indexing array
newData = ['data1', 'data3', 'data2']
```

With that array, I want to get the new order of the `originalPos` array by using `newData` array like this :

```
originalPos = ['50 a', '31 c', '80 b']
```

The goal is to be able to change the position of my waypoints in the Leaflet Routing Machine using `L.routing.machine.spliceWaypoints()`

Comment: do want to sort the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rearrange by finding the position of every element of `originalPos` in `originalData` and with that respective position you can push the element from `newData` into the result array.

**Assuming there is no duplicate data within all three arrays**

```js
const originalData = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
const originalPos = ['50 a', '80 b', '31 c']
const newData = ['data1', 'data3', 'data2']

const newPos = newData.map(n => n && originalPos[originalData.indexOf(n)]);

console.log(newPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the indexes at which the original keys occur in `originalData` (using a Map or plain object). Then map the keys in the new order (`newData`) to the index in that mapping, and take the value at that index in the input data (`originalPos`):

```js
const originalData = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
const originalPos = ['50 a', '80 b', '31 c'];
const newData = ['data1', 'data3', 'data2'];

const map = new Map(originalData.map((val, i) => [val, i])); 
const result = newData.map((val, i) => originalPos[map.get(val)]);
console.log(result);
```

NB: the use of the map will avoid a scan in the first array at each iteration (like with `indexOf`), so giving it a better time complexity.